# php calculation keeps getting the answer as 0

Tags: php, html

this is the index.php file

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    echo header('Location:answer.php');
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label> Insert P value </label>
                <input type="text" name="p" placeholder="please insert your P value">
</div>
<br>

<div class="form-group">
    <label> Insert R value </label>
    <input type="text" name="r" placeholder ="please insert your R value ">
    
</div>
<br>
<div class="form-group">
    <label> Insert your N value </label>

    <input type="text" name="n" placeholder=" please insert your N value">

</div>
<br>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" > Submit </button>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the answer.php file

```
<?php

$p=isset($_POST['p'])?$_POST['p']: " ";
$r=isset($_POST['r'])?$_POST['r']:" ";
$n=isset($_POST['n'])?$_POST['n']: " ";
$si=(int)$p*(int)$r*(int)$n/100;
echo "Hello this is the final answer ".$si;
?>
```

i want the answer to be displayed in another page that is answer.php but whatever number i am inserting i keep getting the answer as 0. Please help and thank you.

Comment: You need to create a form with `action = answer.php`, instead of redirecting the way you do. Your redirect method doesnt send the POST data to the next page, so all your values are empty, and this is why you are getting 0

Comment: ...either do as the suggestion above, or if you want to stay on the same page, you should include that file, not redirect to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I saw from your code. Inside the form tag, you need to add action='answer.php', this is a direct link to the page you are requesting data from, in this case answer.php.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form method="post" action="answer.php">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label> Insert P value </label>
                <input type="text" name="p" placeholder="please insert your P value">
 </div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label> Insert R value </label>
    <input type="text" name="r" placeholder ="please insert your R value ">
</div>
<br>
<div class="form-group">
    <label> Insert your N value </label>

    <input type="text" name="n" placeholder=" please insert your N value">

</div>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" > Submit </button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your form post directly to `answer.php`. By making it post to itself and then redirecting you're losing all the submitted data - it's sent to your index page and then not transmitted again to the answer page. The redirect causes a separate GET request and doesn't contain any of the submitted data.

The other alternative is to move all the logic into `index.php` and not bother with a separate script at all.